# BigQuery TypeError: to_pandas() got an unexpected keyword argument 'timestamp_as_object'

Tags: python, pandas, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

### Environment details

- OS type and version: 1.5.29-debian10
- Python version: 3.7
- `google-cloud-bigquery` version: 2.8.0

I'm provisioning a dataproc cluster which gets the data from BigQuery into a pandas dataframe.
As my data is growing I was looking to boost the performance and heard about using the BigQuery storage client.

I had the same problem in the past and this was solved by setting the google-cloud-bigquery to version 1.26.1.
If I use that version I get the following message.

```
/opt/conda/default/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/cloud/bigquery/client.py:407: UserWarning: Cannot create BigQuery Storage client, the dependency google-cloud-bigquery-storage is not installed.
 "Cannot create BigQuery Storage client, the dependency "
```

The code snippet executes but at a way slower rate. If I do not specify the pip version, I encounter this error.

### Steps to reproduce

1. Cluster creation on dataproc

```
gcloud dataproc clusters create testing-cluster  --region=europe-west1  --zone=europe-west1-b  --master-machine-type n1-standard-16  --single-node  --image-version 1.5-debian10  --initialization-actions gs://dataproc-initialization-actions/python/pip-install.sh  --metadata 'PIP_PACKAGES=elasticsearch google-cloud-bigquery google-cloud-bigquery-storage pandas pandas_gbq'
```

2. Execute the Following script on the cluster

```
bqclient = bigquery.Client(project=project)
job_config = bigquery.QueryJobConfig(
    query_parameters=[
        bigquery.ScalarQueryParameter("query_start", "STRING", str('2021-02-09 00:00:00')),
        bigquery.ScalarQueryParameter("query_end", "STRING", str('2021-02-09 23:59:59.99')),
    ]
)
df = bqclient.query(query, job_config=job_config).to_dataframe(create_bqstorage_client=True)
```

```
2021-02-11 10:10:14,069 - preprocessing logger initialized
2021-02-11 10:10:14,069 - arguments = [file, arg1, arg2, arg3, arg4, project_id, arg5, arg6]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tmp/782503bcc80246258560a07d2179891f/immo_preprocessing-pageviews_kyero.py", line 104, in <module>
    df = bqclient.query(base_query, job_config=job_config).to_dataframe(create_bqstorage_client=True)
  File "/opt/conda/default/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/cloud/bigquery/job/query.py", line 1333, in to_dataframe
    date_as_object=date_as_object,
  File "/opt/conda/default/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/cloud/bigquery/table.py", line 1793, in to_dataframe
    df = record_batch.to_pandas(date_as_object=date_as_object, **extra_kwargs)
  File "pyarrow/array.pxi", line 414, in pyarrow.lib._PandasConvertible.to_pandas
TypeError: to_pandas() got an unexpected keyword argument 'timestamp_as_object'
```

Using the pandas-gbq version gives exaclty the same error

```
query_config = {
    'query': {
        'parameterMode': 'NAMED',         
        'queryParameters': [
            {
                'name': 'query_start',
                'parameterType': {'type': 'STRING'},
                'parameterValue': {'value': str('2021-02-09 00:00:00')}
            },
            {
                'name': 'query_end',
                'parameterType': {'type': 'STRING'},
                'parameterValue': {'value': str('2021-02-09 23:59:59.99')}
            },
        ]
    }
}
df = pd.read_gbq(base_query, 
                 configuration=query_config, 
                 progress_bar_type='tqdm',
                 use_bqstorage_api=True)
```

```
2021-02-11 09:21:19,532 - preprocessing logger initialized
2021-02-11 09:21:19,532 - arguments = [file, arg1, arg2, arg3, arg4, project_id, arg5, arg6]
started
Downloading: 100%|██████████| 3107858/3107858 [00:14<00:00, 207656.33rows/s]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tmp/1830d5bcf198440e9e030c8e42a1b870/immo_preprocessing-pageviews.py", line 98, in <module>
    use_bqstorage_api=True)
  File "/opt/conda/default/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/io/gbq.py", line 193, in read_gbq
    **kwargs,
  File "/opt/conda/default/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas_gbq/gbq.py", line 977, in read_gbq
    dtypes=dtypes,
  File "/opt/conda/default/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas_gbq/gbq.py", line 536, in run_query
    user_dtypes=dtypes,
  File "/opt/conda/default/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas_gbq/gbq.py", line 590, in _download_results
    **to_dataframe_kwargs
  File "/opt/conda/default/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/cloud/bigquery/table.py", line 1793, in to_dataframe
    df = record_batch.to_pandas(date_as_object=date_as_object, **extra_kwargs)
  File "pyarrow/array.pxi", line 414, in pyarrow.lib._PandasConvertible.to_pandas
TypeError: to_pandas() got an unexpected keyword argument 'timestamp_as_object'
```

https://github.com/googleapis/python-bigquery/issues/519

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dataproc installs by default pyarrow 0.15.0 while the bigquery-storage-api needs a more recent version. Manually setting pyarrow to 3.0.0 at install solved the issue.
That being said, PySpark has a compability setting for Pyarrow >= 0.15.0
https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.0.0-preview/sql-pyspark-pandas-with-arrow.html#apache-arrow-in-spark
I've taken a look at the release notes of dataproc and this env variable is set as default since May 2020.

Comment: Can confirm `!pip install pyarrow==3.0.0` solved it for me

Answer (score 6):

@Sam answered this, but I thought I'd just mention the actionable commands:

In a Jupyter notebook:

`!pip install pyarrow==3.0.0`

In your virtualenv

`pip install pyarrow==3.0.0`